# Switch between keyboard languages by CLI in GNOME

Tags: command-line, keyboard-layout, language-support

I'm looking for a way that I can switch keyboard language using Terminal.

[image: input-sources]

There already are some workarounds like `setxkbmap us` [mentioned here](https://superuser.com/questions/404457/how-to-change-input-keyboard-layout-while-in-console).

But this is a workaround, and it does not do certain things (for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> stops working on non-English keyboards, and the language icon in the top-right corner of gnome does not change. This is why `setxkbmap` is not a solution).

Comment: Doing that in a manner which is compatible with the GUI is tricky. The reason is that there is a **M**ost **R**ecently **U**sed dconf key which needs to be maintained. To view the current value of that key you can run: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources mru-sources`

Comment: changing keyboard language.. do you mean to add a new layout or just to change the pre added layout?? I mean if you already selected 3 additional layouts via GUI and you would like to switch between layouts or the other way?

Comment: To switch between the languages (I have edited the question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Already added layouts:***

If you already added input-sources via GUI.. get the list with below command

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources
```

Example:

```
pratap@pratap:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources
[('xkb', 'se'), ('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'ru'), ('xkb', 'de')]
pratap@pratap:~$
```

Count it from 0, 1, 2 & 3 Once you remember the numbering.. use the below command to change the input-sources (replace the number with your choice)

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[2].activate()"
```

Example:

```
pratap@pratap:~$ gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[2].activate()"
(true, '')
pratap@pratap:~$
```

[image]

***to add new layouts:***

In the similar way, you can add new input-sources with `gsettings set` command, the order you want and count it from 0, 1, 2 & 3 etc..

and run the `gdbus` command to switch between input-sources..

Comment: Thanks so much. This is exactly what I wanted. Your solution does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Looks good, but doesn't work. Returns (false, ''). Something changed? Ubuntu 22.04.1 on Wayland.

Comment: It may be possible that that does not anymore work in Gnome 43: I get (false, '')
 as output each time.

Answer (score 0):

List all possible languages:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources
```

Output:

```
[('xkb', 'se'), ('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'ru'), ('xkb', 'de')]
```

To switch language to 'se' (0 - language index, in current case possible indexes 0-3):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 0
```