# Configure separate shortcut keys to switch keyboard layout of current window

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

Using Ubuntu 22.04 with Cinnamon.

I want to configure separate shortcut-keys (for each keyboard layout) to switch the keyboard layout of the current window.

I use the gsettings or system-settings to configure my keyboard layouts.

- switch keyboard layout for each window separately
- and cycle with shortcut key ctrl_left+ctrl_right.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.libgnomekbd.keyboard layouts "['us', 'il', 'br', 'gr']"
gsettings set org.gnome.libgnomekbd.keyboard options "['grp\tgrp:ctrls_toggle']"
gsettings set org.gnome.libgnomekbd.desktop group-per-window true
```

But there isn't an option to configure a separate shortcut key for each layout, instead of cycling (still changing only the current window).

e.g.

```
Super+Shift+1 == switch current window to 'en' 
Super+Shift+2 == switch current window to 'il' 
Super+Shift+3 == switch current window to 'br' 
Super+Shift+4 == switch current window to 'gr'
```

Is there any available settings/program/script to set such custom shortcut-keys?

I do not need to be able to switch all windows together. I only wish to be able to switch the current window.

Please note that questions/answers like the following does *not* solve my problem, becuase  it only works to change the layout for *all* windows. I want to change only current window.
[Separate keyboard shortcuts for switching between keyboard layouts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194787/separate-keyboard-shortcuts-for-switching-between-keyboard-layouts)

Comment: You mean "keyboard layout of current window" instead of "layout of current window"? Your title is currently very misleading. You may want to edit it. Anyway, I do not think you can have different keyboard layouts associated with individual windows. You can have shortcut keys that allow quick switching, though.

Comment: @vanadium, omg, I wasn't thinking about that, thanks.

Comment: @vanadium, however, you can have different keyboard layouts associtated with each window.
There's an option for that which I use (org.gnome.libgnomekbd.desktop group-per-window true).
The keyboard shortcut cycles between my 4 layouts for the current window.
I want to have 4 keyboard shortcuts, one for each layout.

Comment: Answer to do that here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1176703/switch-between-keyboard-languages-by-cli-in-gnome, however I have the impression that that does not work anymore in Gnome 43

Comment: @vanadium, does it fail only because of the safety changes or other reasons?
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412130/dbus-calls-to-gnome-shell-dont-work-under-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: Yes, I did not think of it, but that very likely will be why it does not anymore work.